# Is Erlang designed only for running on a single multicore machine, or can you distribute the processes?

Tags: erlang, distributed, cluster-computing, multiprocessor

My app runs well on my quad-core machine. It is 'embarrasingly parallel', with about 100K processes, and thus nicely suited to run on a cluster of machines. However, I have trouble finding documentation on how to spread all those processes out on all available nodes in the cluster.

The documentation for distributed Erlang seems to focus on server-client apps, where each node is a client running a single app, and you specify manually which node runs which process.

Comment: I think my question was a bit too general, and not quite to the point. However, asking it made me realize what it was that I wanted to know, and then realize I already knew how to do it:

What I need to do is to explicitly say, when I spawn my processes, is: for each node in the cluster, spawn a fraction of the processes on it.

For example, if I have nine identical machines, and one that is twice as fast, I start two nodes on that one, and spawn one eleventh of the total number of processes on each node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can certainly [distribute](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) an Erlang program across multiple cores and computers in a cluster.  It was designed for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the word "transparent" when describing Erlang processes. There is no code you need to change if you decide to run the process on another host.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there at all support in Erlang for making a single parallel app run on distributed processor cores?

Certainly! But it depends on how you designed your app. An "ideal" distributable Erlang application is actually built from a number of independent (Erlang) processes that communicate with each other via the messaging system, in order to perform computations.